# Link Google Sheet reference to <script> section on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I have created a HTML Landing Page which used a `Google Sheets Doc as a CMS.`

So far everything works great and links to specific elements on the GS Doc `(Content, Images, Links, etc).`

I need to link a few different  codes that are in the GS Doc to the HTML but I am having trouble finding a way to do this as it does not work in the same format as the other references.

Example:

```
$("#pageTitle").html(values[0][0]);
$("#favIcon").attr("href",values[0][1])
$("#paymentTitle").html(values[0][4]);
$("#paymentDes").html(values[0][5]);
$("#paymentImage").attr("src",values[0][6])
```

What format does a  need to be added to this list above for it to read the code corrently?

Let me know if I have not explained this clearly (as I am not a developer, just code here and there).

Thanks.